# Detach process from terminal when SIGTSTP

Tags: c, unix, signals

I'm trying to handle signal SIGTSTP to have possibility to restore a program after SIGCONT signal. First I need terminate my program from current tty, but I don't know how to do this. I found this solution, but I don't understand why it works. Are the other ways how I can do it?

```
ioctl(g_fd, TIOCSTI, "\x1A");
```

The part of my program that handles signals.

```
void            signal_handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGINT || sig == SIGSTOP)
        correct_escape();
    else if (sig == SIGTSTP)
    {
        restore_termconf();
        signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
        ioctl(g_fd, TIOCSTI, "\x1A");
    }
    else if (sig == SIGCONT)
    {
        init_termcap();
        g_termconf = configure_tty();
        display_files();
    }
    else if (sig == SIGWINCH)
        display_files();
}

void            setup_signals(struct termios termconf)

{

g_termconf = termconf;

signal(SIGWINCH, signal_handler);
signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
signal(SIGSTOP, signal_handler);
signal(SIGTSTP, signal_handler);
signal(SIGCONT, signal_handler);
}
```

Comment: Note: you attempt to register a signal handler for `SIGSTOP`, but `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught (unlike `SIGTSTP`).

Comment: Why do you think you need to "terminate [your] program from current tty"?  Or at least, why do you think that your program is responsible for doing that itself?  If it is receiving job-control signals then whatever process is sending them can be expected to handle the terminal.  Moreover, while your process is stopped, it cannot access the terminal (or do anything else), so why would it need to actively be disconnected?

Comment: I don't understand what it's doing, either. `signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL)` means that if it gets a second `SIGTSTP` later, it won't be handled. I'm also not sure what the purpose of the `TIOCSTI` is, but maybe it depends on what `g_fd` refers to.

Comment: It looks like the code you present is focused on saving and restoring the terminal's configuration, apparently so as not to surprise other processes using it wile this one is stopped.  That's a completely different thing from disconnecting from the terminal.

Comment: I use g_fd to resolve fd of tty, if stdout of program was redirected, so g_fd always(in most common situations) correspond to ttys output. If i dont use SIG_DFL, program spams to output ^Z and it is pernament loop. I too, 
dont understand how it works so i am here).

Comment: If i dont call ioctl, program will stop writing to terminal, but control will not be returned to bash.

Comment: Just do `kill(getpid(), SIGTSTP)` instead of `ioctl(g_fd, TIOCSTI, "\x1A")`. There's no requirement that the user uses 0x1A (Ctrl-Z) as the suspend character.